# Find trace of the matrix A

Tags: matrices

Let$A=[a_{i,j}]$ be a $n\times n$ rowed square matrix$\left(1\leq i,j\leq n\right)$,where $a_{ij}=u_{i}v_{j}$ and $u_{i}\in R$ and $v_{j}\in R$.

Also,$A$ also satisfies the equation $A^{5}=16A$.

Find value of $trace(A)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that this matrix has the rank $1$ or $0$. In the last case  the trace is $0$ and in the former case we have $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $\lambda\ne0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $1$. Since the polynomial $x^5-16x=x(x^4-16)$ annihilates this symmetric real matrix then the possible real values  of $\lambda$ are $2$ and $-2$ so the trace is $\lambda=\pm2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A=uv^T\implies A^5=(v^Tu)^4 A\implies v^Tu=2\implies Tr(A)=Tr(uv^T)=Tr(v^Tu)=v^Tu=\pm2$ assuming $A\ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: @Samrat Mukhopadhyay.If$A=uv^{T}$ then how come $A^{5}=\left(v^{T}u\right)^{4}A$. I am not able to understand this step.

Comment: Note that, in this case, $A^2=uv^Tuv^T=(v^Tu)uv^T=(v^Tu)A$, I could do this because $v^Tu$ is a scalar. Now carry out this for $A^5$

Comment: .Isn't $v^{T}u$ a $1\times 1$ matrix.So how is it a scalar.

Comment: A $1\times 1$ matrix is nothing but a number i.e. a scalar.

Comment: Ok.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, as answered by Sami Ben Romdhane, by Cayley-Hamilton theorem the matrix satisfies the equation $A(A-v^Tu I)=0$ from which also the result follows. Actually this should be the correct way to approach solving this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is lack of information.

If $A$ is the null matrix, you have $trace(A)=0$ and also $A^5=16A$...

If $A=kI$, then $k^4=16$, $k=\pm 2$, thus $trace(A)=\pm 2\times n$.

EDIT: I missed the point that $a_{ij}=u_iv_j$, thus the restriction on the rank of $A$...

Comment: We cannot have $A=kI$ for $k\not= 0 $when $A=uv^T$.