# solving for eigenvalues & eigenvectors of the product of a column vector and row vector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a problem in my studies and am trying to prove it.  I have worked so far, but need some advice as to whether I'm handling it correctly:

Let $v$ be a column vector of size $n$ and let $A = vv^t$ be an $n x n $ matrix.  How many non-zero eigenvalues does this matrix A have?   Also what are the eigenvalues of A and what are the corresponding eigenvectors?

so far I have the following $$ A = vv^t $$ $$ Av=\lambda v $$ $$vv^t (v) = \lambda v$$  the non-zero eigenvalues is the n power of its characteristic polynomial given by equation  $$P_A(t) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (t - \lambda_i)$$ n is the amount of eigenvalues.

Because this matrix is diagonalizable, the eigenvalues can be found with matrix $P$ as the eigenvectors  $$P^{-1} vv^tP = D$$ the eigenvalues are the diagonal of $D$

Comment: I suppose your matrix is $A=v^tv$ and, if so, notice that any row is proportional to $v$ so that his rank is at most $1$..

Comment: a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143472/find-trace-of-the-matrix-a/1143488#1143488

Comment: I know that the rank is the dimension of its image and is related to its nullity.  Does that mean that if the rank is 1 it has 1 eigenvalue and 1 eigenvector?   I am sorry but can you please explain further?

Comment: Yes. If the rank is $1$ then $0$ is an eigenvalue of multilicity $n-1$.